# Code runs well, but My Database isn't chaged at all.(Json to SQLITE database in Python)

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite

umm
now I am crawling tweet including "BTC" and got JSON file.
and I am moving these file to the sqlite database.
i want to select 4 columns ['tweet_id', 'text', 'user_id', 'timestamp']

I made some code and this does not show any TRACKBACK ERROR.

So I think, the database which is inserted data from JSON should be changed,
but nothing changed.

here is my code

so I am just stuck on this problem. python didn't show anything...

```
import sqlite3

data = sqlite3.connect("bit_kor_2.sqlite")
cur = data.cursor()



import json

bitkor = json.load(open('bit_kor.json'))


columns = ['tweet_id', 'text', 'user_id', 'timestamp']



for data2 in bitkor:
    keys= []
    for i in columns:
        keys.append(data2[i])
    print(keys)
    #keys = tuple(data2[c] for c in columns)
    #print(str(keys))
    cur = data.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into test values (?,?,?,?)", (keys))
    cur.close()
    print('ok')
```

Comment: after execute : `cur.commit()`

Comment: Thank you sir! in my case, data.commit() was the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
cur.commit()
```

after cur.execute()